# Pick out certain lines from files

Tags: list, testing, tcl

I am writing a tcl script that reads from a file and displays certain lines from this file. I can read from the file n problem but I cant figure out how to pick out certain lines BEFORE filtering out what I don't need. I am reading the file to a list and then using the following code to filter it out;

```
proc listFromFile {/.../.../.../file_test.file} {
set f [open /.../.../.../file_test.file r]
set data [split [string trim [read $f]]]
close $f
return $data
}
set f [listFromFile /.../.../.../file_test.file]
set f [lsort -unique $f]
set f [lsearch -all -inline $f "test_*"
```

The lines within the file look like

```
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, other, test_runtest1 ...
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, KEYWORD, test_runtest2 ...
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, KEYWORD, test_runtest3 ...
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, other, test_runtest4 ...
```

How would I pick out the lines containing KEYWORD as a whole before I filter out everything else I don't need? The lines containing KEYWORD are randomly within the file along with other tests. Is this a possibility at all?

Comment: Now _that_ is an unexpected name for a formal parameter variable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be hard. To begin with, you probably want to split the file's contents at the line breaks:

```
set data [split [string trim [read $f]] \n]
```

When you've done that, you could use a number of techniques to select the lines you want, for instance

```
lsearch -all -inline $data *KEYWORD*
```

Documentation: [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm), [read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly. Ive searched everywhere I didn't think it would be something so subtle. Life saver :)

Comment: Are you talking about the having it read from a different directory? The test file is under a different directory than where the tcl script will be running. Im pretty new with tcl so any suggestions are welcome

Comment: @LiamP: no, I'm talking about passing argument values into a command. Take a look [here](http://www.beedub.com/book/2nd/tclintro.doc.html) for instance (scroll down to "Procedures").

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly consider

```
set lines [split [exec grep -Fw KEYWORD file_test.file] \n]
```

Otherwise

```
proc select_lines {filename keyword} {
    set fid [open $filename r]
    while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
        if {[string match "*$keyword*" $line]} {lappend lines $line}
    }
    close $fid
    return $lines
}
set lines [select_lines file_test.file KEYWORD]
```